# Find and swap occurrences in text

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with the following as input:

```
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '1' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '2'
update dbo.und set und_ben = '' where und_k = 'UB' AND und_ben = 'Bl'
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '3' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '4'
update dbo.und set und_ben = '' where und_k = 'PC' AND und_ben = 'Bo'
```

What I would like to do is to replace the first `ab_snus` data with the second `ab_snus` data, as well as swap `und_ben` data, so that the output would be:

```
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '2' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '1'
update dbo.und set und_ben = 'Bl' where und_k = 'UB' AND und_ben = ''
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '4' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '3'
update dbo.und set und_ben = 'Bo' where und_k = 'PC' AND und_ben = ''
```

The majority of these columns can be collected with the regex `'([a-zA-Z\d]+)'`, but for empty columns, i.e. `''`, I am at a loss, bar using some sort of `re.finditer(r'\'\'')`.

`'([a-zA-Z\d]+)'` will also match `und_k`, which is a no-go.

```
import re
text = '''
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '1' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '2'
update dbo.und set und_ben = '' where und_k = 'UB' AND und_ben = 'Bl'
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '3' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '4'
update dbo.und set und_ben = '' where und_k = 'PC' AND und_ben = 'Bo'
'''
matchsnus, matchund = [], []
for match in re.finditer(r'\'([a-zA-Z\d]+)\'', text):
    matchsnus.append(match.group(0))
    print(matchsnus)
```

will return the output of:
`['2', 'aeiou', '1', 'Bl', 'UB', '4', 'aeiou', '3', 'Bo', 'PC']`. Would a reasonable approach be to find all occurrences of `ab_snus` and `und_ben`, append them to their respective array, and then apply some logic to swap match 0 with 1, 2 with 3, etc?

**TL;DR**: How do I swap the data in each line for`ab_snus` and `und_ben?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two passes substitution with `re.sub()` function:

```
import re

text = '''
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '1' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '2'
update dbo.und set und_ben = '' where und_k = 'UB' AND und_ben = 'Bl'
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '3' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '4'
update dbo.und set und_ben = '' where und_k = 'PC' AND und_ben = 'Bo'
'''

text = re.sub(r"(update .+\bab_snus = ')([^']*)(' .+\bab_snus = ')([^']*)'", "\\1\\4\\3\\2'", text)
text = re.sub(r"(update .+\bund_ben = ')([^']*)(' .+\bund_ben = ')([^']*)'", "\\1\\4\\3\\2'", text)

print(text)
```

The output:

```
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '2' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '1'
update dbo.und set und_ben = 'Bl' where und_k = 'UB' AND und_ben = ''
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '4' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '3'
update dbo.und set und_ben = 'Bo' where und_k = 'PC' AND und_ben = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\b((ab_snus|und_ben)\s*=\s*)('\w*')(.*\b\2\s*=\s*)('\w*')
```

and replace with `\1\5\4\3`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ABveDR/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `((ab_snus|und_ben)\s*=\s*)` - Group 1 (referenced to with `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern):

  - `(ab_snus|und_ben)` - Group 2 (referenced to with `\2` backreference from the replacement and regex pattern): either `ab_snus` or `und_ben`
  - `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `('\w*')` - Group 3 (referenced to with `\3` backreference from the replacement pattern): a `'`, zero or more word chars (you may also use `[^']*` to match 0+ chars other than `'`), `'`
- `(.*\b\2\s*=\s*)` - Group 4 (referenced to with `\4` backreference from the replacement pattern):

  - `.*\b\2` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the same value as captured in Group 2 (matched as a whole word due to the word boundary)
  - `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `('\w*')` - Group 5 (referenced to with `\5` backreference from the replacement pattern): a `'`, zero or more word chars (you may also use `[^']*` to match 0+ chars other than `'`), `'`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/O7cBqQ):

```
import re
rx = r"\b((ab_snus|und_ben)\s*=\s*)('\w*')(.*\b\2\s*=\s*)('\w*')"
s = ("update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '1' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '2'\n"
    "update dbo.und set und_ben = '' where und_k = 'UB' AND und_ben = 'Bl'\n"
    "update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '3' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '4'\n"
    "update dbo.und set und_ben = '' where und_k = 'PC' AND und_ben = 'Bo'")
result = re.sub(rx, r"\1\5\4\3", s)
print (result)
```

Result:

```
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '2' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '1'
update dbo.und set und_ben = 'Bl' where und_k = 'UB' AND und_ben = ''
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '4' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '3'
update dbo.und set und_ben = 'Bo' where und_k = 'PC' AND und_ben = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to use regex when you can do this job simply without importing that :

```
with open('current.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=line.split()
        data[5],data[13]=data[13],data[5]
        with open('new_file.txt','a') as ff:
            ff.write(" ".join(data)+'\n')
```

output:

```
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '2' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '1'
update dbo.und set und_ben = 'Bl' where und_k = 'UB' AND und_ben = ''
update dbo.pc set ab_snus = '4' where ab_pb = 'aeiou' and ab_snus = '3'
update dbo.und set und_ben = 'Bo' where und_k = 'PC' AND und_ben = ''
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - this is a very neat solution.